# Can nginx be configured to allow a path like /api to pass through, and add a header to the request

Tags: ajax, api, nginx, jetty

I am using NGINX as my web server for html/js/css files and my web app UI. It is a single page app that uses AJAX requests to a back end JEtty server. Previously I deployed everything in Jetty and ajax calls worked fine. In separating the back end from the web UI tier, I am now trying to figure out how to configure NGINX to allow AJAX requests to pass through to Jetty. But, I ALSO want to prevent someone from watching network traffic and seeing the ajax calls my app makes, then scripting those themselves. To do this, I believe if I can configure nginx to ADD a custom header to the requests as they pass through (is this even possible?) I could then only accept requests with those headers at my Jetty API level.

If that is possible, is it the right way to handle this so that outsiders can't get in to my back end API? Is there a way they could figure out that my nginx server is adding a header short of breaking in to my server and figuring out the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application calls your api via Ajax on the client there's nothing you can do to stop someone from calling it directly (assuming they otherwise have access to the page). At the end of the day, an Ajax request is just a request made from the client in JS. Now, there are lots of stupid ways to make it more *difficult*, but, if anyone *really* wants to call your api directly, they can.

If you're just talking about only allowing access through nginx (or specifically your /api location block), just bind jetty to localhost only.

Comment: The ajax request would still need to go to http://<mydomain>/api/... from a remote browser or other client though. Not sure how binding jetty to localhost would work? Especially because ideally in production I'd probably have a couple jetty servers sitting behind a load balancer, such that the load balancer ip (assuming in the same network) would be the server the nginx front end web server would send to.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do then? Whoops hit send, still writing...

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do? I feel like we're on the same page with "it's impossible to make it so that the only client that can access the api is your web app", so you want to make it so the api is accessible via yourdomain/api, but won't respond to requests sent directly to your LB or jetty server ips? Depending on where/how you're hosted this could be pretty easy (check out VPC if you're on aws), but adding a header is possible with the proxy_set_header directive.

Comment: alternatively you could probably just use strict iptables rules to block all incoming connections except those from your nginx server.

Comment: You are correct on all accounts I believe. I figured out the configuration somewhat with nginx and the default server, adding extra location blocks and the one that proxys is set up to use /api which works. I also found another site that indicated the same sort of iptable thing to block all traffic except from my internal server. For dev purposes, everything runs on my laptop, although I'll probably set up some KVM instances to simulate separate servers. Thanks again for you replies.